# Cron job is not executing Python script

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a script that should run every 30 min every day.

```
 30 * * * * python /home/pi/MyScript.py
```

I used every min to test it

```
 1 * * * * python /home/pi/MyScript.py
```

but it's not executing, did I used the wrong path? or is the minute not correctly?

Comment: This will **not** fire every minute. It will fire every hour when the number of minutes is `1`. So at `00:01`, `01:01`, etc. You should write `* * * * * python ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand the syntax.

In your first example, you tell `cron` to run `MyScript.py` at the `30th` minute of each hour (ie `10:30`), not every `30` minutes.

In the second example, `MyScript.py` is run at the `1st` minute of each hour (ie `10:01`), not every minute.

You probably want to do this:

```
*/30 * * * * python /home/pi/MyScript.py
```

Now, your script will run every `30` minutes (at `10:00`, `10:30`, `11:00` etc.). You can change `30` to whatever interval you desire.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run something every 30 min then the `crontab` should be something like this

```
*/30 * * * * python /home/pi/MyScript.py
```

Or for every 1 min like this.

```
*/1 * * * * python /home/pi/MyScript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
1 * * * * python /home/pi/MyScript.py
```

will **not fire every minute**. It will fire every hour when the number of minutes is equal to `1` so `00:01`, `01:01`, `02:01`, etc. In order for the script to fire every minute, you should write:

```
* * * * * python /home/pi/MyScript.py
```

and in case you want the script to fire every 30 minutes, you can for instance write:

```
0,30 * * * * python /home/pi/MyScript.py
```

Now the script will fire at `00:00`, `00:30`, `01:00`, `01:30`, etc.

Comment: Hmm, i changed it but it is not executing. Maybe the path?

Comment: @user7998549: can you inspect the `journalctl`. Usually errors generated by cron are listed there.

Comment: Wel nothing to see there, I have no clue tbh

Comment: @user7998549: can you write `* * * * * python /home/pi/MyScript.py > ~/log.log 2> ~/log.err` such that `cron` will write stdout and stderr to files you can then inspect?

Comment: Ok tbh i'm very new to Python

Comment: @user7998549: this has  nothing to do with Python itself, this is I/O redirection, that is a part of the shell.

Comment: Let's say i'm more familiar with .NET and UI then the command prompt